# incorrect jQuery height

Tags: jquery

I have a page with two columns and try to make them the same height using jQuery... I have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
        var right_column_height = $("#right-column-wrapper").height()
        var content_height = $("#content-wrapper").height()
        console.log("content = " + content_height)

        if(right_column_height > content_height) $("#content-wrapper").css("height", right_column_height)
        else $("#right-column-wrapper").css("height", content_height)
})
</script>
```

if right column is higher, its working correctly, but when when the content is higher, its acting weirdly...
on one page the height is set as expected, on other page its not working at all...
I added console logging to see whats happening and I see that the content height is not calculated in jQuery... but when I then enter the same code to console, I get a corret value... 
Can you suggest what's wrong in my code please...

See the demo at http://demo.romanpriryl.cz, the problematic page is http://beta.romanprikryl.cz/fotogalerie.htm, but working correctly on http://beta.romanprikryl.cz/objednavky.htm

Comment: Try adding `px` to the value: `$("#right-column-wrapper").css("height", content_height + "px");` without it, other unit might be applied. Also, if the content wrapper has absolute positioned or floating elements, the height won't be calculated properly because of this..

Comment: I first used $("#right-column-wrapper").css("height") to get the height and that gives the values with 'px', but the result was the same

Answer (score 4):

I've solved my issue when I put the code for resizing into the setTimeout function...
a delay of 1 milisecond is enough, but still I dont understand why it's not working wihtout this... probably the page height is somehow calculated after the document is ready

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using javascript to solve a problem that can easily fixed using CSS ?

See for instance [this tutorial](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/) and [this one as well](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

Comment: I'm using gradient background and rounded corners on the divs, so with the given examples it would look weird... or I just didn't figure out how to use them correctly in my case... If you know, please suggest, I would better use the CSS then JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If either the #right-column-wrapper or the #content-wrapper elements have images without specified dimensions then jQuery will return the height of the container minus this image heights.

This happens because the images haven't loaded yet on $(document).ready() (this is also the most likely reason why a setTimeout is working).

To fix this, place the code where you want to get the element heights inside $(window).load().

e.g.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var right_column_height = $("#right-column-wrapper").height()
    var content_height = $("#content-wrapper").height()
    console.log("content = " + content_height)

    if(right_column_height > content_height) $("#content-wrapper").css("height", right_column_height)
    else $("#right-column-wrapper").css("height", content_height)
});
```

Alternatively you can set the image width and height in HTML and jQuery will determine the correct height values for your elements.